# All mappings from $\mathbb{R}^N$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$ where the image of any line segment is a line segment

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I know that a projective transformation maps a line segment to a line segment. Are there mappings other than projective transformations where the image of any line segment is a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your definition of a "projective transformation"?

Comment: @uniquesolution See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography and https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html I think it is sometimes referred to as a perspective transformation as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Wikipedia article on projective transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography), all collineations in real projective spaces are projective transformations.  A collineation is a one-to-one mapping of lines.

You could think of a collineation as preserving collinearity of points.  I.e. any three collinear points are mapped to three points that are in turn collinear.  But any three collinear points sit on a common line segment, so the any map that takes line segments to line segments preserves collinearity and hence is a collineation and in turn a projective transformation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize that all collineations in real projective spaces are projective transformations.

Comment: @XuZhang, if you are happy with the answer you can upvote and mark as accepted.